# The caption package and letterspacing

Tags: captions, small-caps, microtype, letterspacing

## Problem Statement

I adjusted the caption format for my figures and tables using the `caption` package, such that the words "Figure" and "Table" are typeset using small caps. Now I want to obtain correct letterspacing for these words using the `microtype` package and the command `\textls`, but adding `labelfont = ls` in the caption setup doesn't work.

## Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    format = plain,
    font = footnotesize,
    labelfont = sc
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A circle.}
    \label{fig:sine}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Sample output

> [image: caption]

Note the non-letterspaced small caps here.

Comment: Add `\DeclareCaptionFont{ls}{\lsstyle}` and then `labelfont={sc,ls}` should give you spaced small caps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The KOMA-script classes have their own method for changing basic aspects of the caption typesetting. On the other hand, the `caption` package allows greater flexibility and many more customization options.

Since the package can't know each and every font combination, it also provide an interface for defining new options.

In your case you can do

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{ls}{\lsstyle} % define a new option

\captionsetup{
  format = plain,
  font = footnotesize,
  labelfont = {sc,ls},
}
```

See Section 4 “Own enhancements” in the documentation of `caption`.

Answer (score 6):

As you're using `scrartcl`, there's no reason to use the `caption` package if all you do with it is set the caption's text style. This can be done out of the box with the `komascript` classes (and, differently, with others too).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setkomafont{caption}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\usekomafont{caption}\scshape\lsstyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{...}
...
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately limited to the KOMA documentclasses.

Comment: well, the KOMA classes is what you're using `:)` Plus, if a package (or a class) can change LaTeX's defaults, there's no reason why you couldn't do it too. I like to keep the Nr. of packages loaded small, so if I were using a class other than `scr*`, and if all wanted was to change the caption style, I'd just look up how `caption` or `scr*` does it and build my own mechanism based on that.